# Downloading a an excel file overwrites another file with same name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't even begin to describe my frustration with this. I had a file named Math-319 grades that I have been updating weekly and sent it via e-mail to my professor. After that I had made multiple update to that file on my laptop, then today I needed to look up what was on the earlier version that I e-mailed last week. So when I downloaded *that earlier version* from my e-mail, it actually overrwrote the newest version of my file that is on my laptop.

How does this make sense to begin with?

**EDIT.** I managed to recover the old file, but it took me hours. The attachment was downloaded from my e-mail account which uses Microsoft Outlook e-mail client. The only options were to "View" and "Download". I still find it very strange not to have other options.

Comment: If you've downloaded it to the same location with the same name then it'll overwrite the previous file. That's by design. You could set up a backup to have a copy if the same happens in the future.

Comment: literally every other program has a prompt saying "there is already a file named X, would you wanna replace it?.." . But why on earth excel does not have that option? That's just beyond me.

Comment: Was that only this time you wasn't warned, or is it always like this for Excel? Are you really sure you didn't pressed OK for that question? Maybe by accident as you tried to click something else, or just pressed enter at the wrong moment?

Comment: to be more clear: we can answer question which are based on reproducible issues.

Comment: Excel doesn't process email. You said you downloaded the file from your email, so it is whatever program or browser you are using that overwrote the file, not Excel.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question, by using the [edit] link to add details so readers do not have to read the comments to get the whole story? As is, we can not tell you why it would, or would not, make sense because we don't know exactly what you did. Also, what does "triggering" mean?

Comment: Sounds like you inadvertently saved the file as the wrong name somewhere down the line without knowing it. Look at the time stamp in "details" column in the folder view. You can try and look in your "temp files" and pull out an earlier version -- maybe you can get something there, but remember to save-as and rename it and to a different location as to not further confuse yourself. There are tools to grab old file from the heap (unattainable free space) also.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you do when you 'download' a document.  When you 'download' the document are you actually saving to a location in your downloads or documents folder, or are you somehow working off a copy stored in your temporary files?  If you are working off something in the temporary files folder, it would not surprise me at all that it got wiped out when you 'downloaded' a new copy.  Simply clicking on a document attached to an email is not a download.  You need to actually save it somewhere, if you don't want to lose it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just click or double-click on an E-mail attachment what the computer usually does (different E-mail clients vary on paths) is:

- Download the file to a temporary folder
- Simulate the "double-click" action (based on OS, that usually means open file from existing location with default program associated with the files extension).

Unfortunately there isn't anything we can do that will change this default action Microsoft pioneered (15-25+? years ago) and the proverbial everyone duplicated that action.

If you ever want to make sure you never loose data you you have to change your habits in one of two ways. Either:

- Never double-click an E-mail attachment.
- Always right-click an E-mail attachment | choose Save As | specify a permanent location (eg Desktop or Documents).
- Navigate to that location using your file browser/explorer and double-click the file to open

OR

- If you double-click any E-mail attachment and are planning to do anything other than discard/close with no changes.
- Stop.
- Immediately use the Programs File | Save As function and give it a permanent logical location (eg Desktop or Documents). Note: when you're doing this, you'll probably be starting in that temporary location so you have to watch your path indicators.
- Now you can continue editing/changing the contents of the file, and the program will now prompt you to save changes when you close, and will be using the path you used when you used the Save As function.

Anything outside these two actions, and results will be unique per OS/Email client and be unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem was unique with the client which is Microsoft Outlook e-mail client that our school uses. There was no "Save as" option on either right-click or left-click. The only options were to View and Download.